# Reducing iterator based on value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an iterator as such:

```
Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 2015), List(5, 2017), List(7, 2020))
```

I'm trying to return an iterator, but with the values slightly changed. The values for all multiples of 5 must be added to the previous row. So the result would be:

```
Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 4032), List(7, 2020))
```

I've tried using the following method:

```
val a = Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 2015), List(5, 2017), List(7, 2020))

val aTransformed = a.reduce((x,y) => if (y(0)%5 == 0) List(x(0),x(1)+y(1)) else x)
```

but it gives me the final value `val aTransformed: List[Int] = List(1, 4029)`

What can I do to get an iterator in my desired format? Is there a method to just check the previous/next row without folding it all into one final value?

I know this is possible by converting the iterator to a List, traversing, mutating and converting back to an iterator, but is there a more elegant solution?

Edit for clarification:

Consecutive multiples of 5 will get collated into one sum

Ex:

```
Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 2015), List(5, 2017), List(10, 2025))
```

should become

```
Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 6057))
```

Comment: Will there ever be consecutive multiples of five? And if so, should they all get collated into one sum, or should each one be added (piecemeal) to the previous one in the resulting list?

Comment: Yes they should

Comment: Edited the question to clarify

Comment: Does the outer data structure have to be an iterator? since  you cant fetch the last  element from iterator unless you traverse it.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I'm going to be reading in very large files, so I have to read it into an iterator. I have no issues with solving this with Lists, but was just wondering if there was a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we cant directly get last element from `Iterator`, we need a buffer to store the last element, and after calcuate, we check the buffer state and append it the final result.

Here I append a empty `Iterator[List[Int]]` element to simplify the check step.

```scala
def convert(xs: Iterator[List[Int]]): Iterator[List[Int]] = {
      val res = (xs ++ Iterator(List[Int]())).foldLeft(Iterator[List[Int]](), List[Int]())((x, y)=> {
        if (y.nonEmpty && y(0) % 5 == 0) {
          if (x._2.nonEmpty) {
            (x._1, List(x._2(0), x._2(1) + y(1)))
          } else {
            (x._1, y)
          }
        } else {
          if (x._2.nonEmpty) {
            (x._1 ++ Iterator(x._2), y)
          } else {
            (x._1, y)
          }
        }
      })

      res._1
    }
```

test

```
scala> val xs1 = Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 2015), List(5, 2017), List(7, 2020))
val xs1: Iterator[List[Int]] = <iterator>

scala> val xs2 = Iterator(List(1, 2012), List(2, 2015), List(5, 2017), List(10, 2025))
val xs2: Iterator[List[Int]] = <iterator>

scala> convert(xs1)
val res44: Iterator[List[Int]] = <iterator>

scala> res44.toList
val res45: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2012), List(2, 4032), List(7, 2020))


scala> convert(xs2)
val res47: Iterator[List[Int]] = <iterator>

scala> res47.toList
val res48: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2012), List(2, 6057))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a possible way to get the expected result. I haven't checked all the possibilities..

```
val interResult = itr.foldLeft((List.empty[List[Int]], List.empty[Int])) { (acc, curr) =>
    if(curr.size != 2)
      acc
    else if(acc._2.isEmpty)
      (acc._1, curr)
    else
      if(curr.headOption.exists(_ % 5 == 0))
        (acc._1, List(acc._2.head, acc._2.last + curr.last))
      else
        (acc._1 :+ acc._2, curr)
  }

interResult._1 :+ interResult._2
```